# How do I save Parser feed sqlite Database in Offline?

Tags: android, sqlite, rss

When I am offline the data should show me that image should be saved to the sqlite database. I need offline rss feed auto update I want to see the data in them.Save sqlite database.Below is the rss feed on how to connect this to sqlite. If anyone has any please help me Show me all data offline All data must be saved

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;


import com.Tamillive.newspaper.util.Helper;
import com.Tamillive.newspaper.util.InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.Tamillive.newspaper.util.Log;
import com.Tamillive.newspaper.util.ThemeUtils;
import com.Tamillive.newspaper.util.ViewModeUtils;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

/**
 * This activity is used to display a list of rss items
 */

public class RssFragment extends Fragment {

    private RSSFeed rssFeed = null;
    private ArrayList<RSSItem> postsList;
    private RssAdapter listAdapter;
    private ViewModeUtils viewModeUtils;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    private Activity mAct;
    private RelativeLayout ll;
    private String url;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private View rootView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ll = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_refresh, container, false);
        return ll;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        RecyclerView listView = ll.findViewById(R.id.list);
        postsList = new ArrayList<>();
        listAdapter = new RssAdapter(getContext(), postsList);
        listAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_PROGRESS);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        swipeRefreshLayout = ll.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refreshItems();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mAct = getActivity();

//        url = RssFragment.this.getArguments().getStringArray(MainActivity.FRAGMENT_DATA)[0];
        refreshItems();
    }

    private class RssTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                URL rssUrl = new URL("http://www.rssmix.com/u/12847959/rss.xml");
                SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
                RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
                myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
                InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
                myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

                rssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | SAXException e) {
                Log.printStackTrace(e);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (rssFeed != null) {
                if (rssFeed.getList().size() > 0) {
                    postsList.addAll(rssFeed.getList());
                }

                listAdapter.setHasMore(false);
                listAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_LIST);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            } else {
                String message = null;
                if (!url.startsWith("http"))
                    message = "Debug info: '" + url + "' is most likely not a valid RSS url. Make sure the url entered in your configuration starts with 'http' and verify if it's valid XML using https://validator.w3.org/feed/";
                Helper.noConnection(mAct, message);

                listAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_EMPTY);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.rss_menu, menu);
        viewModeUtils = new ViewModeUtils(getContext(), getClass());
        viewModeUtils.inflateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        ThemeUtils.tintAllIcons(menu, mAct);
    }

    private void refreshItems() {
        postsList.clear();
        listAdapter.setModeAndNotify(InfiniteRecyclerViewAdapter.MODE_PROGRESS);
        new RssTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        viewModeUtils.handleSelection(item, new ViewModeUtils.ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void modeChanged() {
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.info:
                //show information about the feed in general in a dialog
                if (rssFeed != null) {
                    String FeedTitle = (rssFeed.getTitle());
                    String FeedDescription = (rssFeed.getDescription());
                    //String FeedPubdate = (myRssFeed.getPubdate()); most times not present
                    String FeedLink = (rssFeed.getLink());

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mAct);

                    String titlevalue = getResources().getString(R.string.feed_title_value);
                    String descriptionvalue = getResources().getString(R.string.feed_description_value);
                    String linkvalue = getResources().getString(R.string.feed_link_value);

                    if (FeedLink.equals("")) {
                        builder.setMessage(titlevalue + ": \n" + FeedTitle +
                                "\n\n" + descriptionvalue + ": \n" + FeedDescription);
                    } else {
                        builder.setMessage(titlevalue + ": \n" + FeedTitle +
                                "\n\n" + descriptionvalue + ": \n" + FeedDescription +
                                "\n\n" + linkvalue + ": \n" + FeedLink);
                    }

                    builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok), null)
                            .setCancelable(true);
                    builder.create();
                    builder.show();

                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```